# How can you solve $y''=\delta(t-c)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So if $c\geq0$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $y(0)=a$, $y'(0)=b$ how can I solve $y''=\delta(t-c)$ with Laplace transforms?

What I have so far is

$$s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)=e^{-cs} \\
s^2Y(s)-sa-b=e^{-cs} \\
Y(s) = \frac{e^{-cs}}{s^2}+\frac{a}{s}+\frac{b}{s^2} \\
y(t) = \begin{cases} a+bt \mbox {   if 0}  \leq \mbox{ t < c} \\
\mbox{something} \mbox{ if c}\leq\mbox{ t }
\end{cases}
$$

I am having trouble finding the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{e^{-cs}}{s^2}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{{\rm y}\pars{0} = a\,,\quad{\rm y}'\pars{0} = b\,,\quad c > 0}$.

---

$$
{\rm y}''\pars{t} = \delta\pars{t - c}\ \imp\
{\rm y}'\pars{t} - {\rm y}'\pars{0} = \int_{0}^{t}\delta\pars{\tau - c}\,\dd\tau 
\ \imp\ {\rm y}'\pars{t} = b + \Theta\pars{t - c}
$$
where $\ds{\Theta\pars{t}}$ is the
[Heaviside Step Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

---

$$
{\rm y}\pars{t} - {\rm y}\pars{0}
=\int_{0}^{t}\bracks{b + \Theta\pars{\tau - c}}\,\dd\tau
=bt + \Theta\pars{t - c}\int_{c}^{t}\dd\tau
=bt + \Theta\pars{t - c}\pars{t - c}
$$

---

$$
\bbox[15px,border:1px solid black]{\ds{%
{\rm y}\pars{t} =a + bt + \Theta\pars{t - c}\pars{t - c}}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this one directly, using the definition of the dirac delta. Integrate both sides over $(0,t)$.

$$ \int_0^t y''(\tau) \,d\tau = \int_0^t \delta(\tau-c)\,d\tau. $$

This evaluates to

$$ y'(t)-y'(0) = \begin{cases} 0 & t<c \\ 1 & t \geq c. \end{cases} $$

Integrating again, we have
$$ y(t)-y(0)-ty'(0) = \begin{cases} 0 & t < c \\ t-c & t \geq c. \end{cases} $$

Bringing things around and using $a=y(0)$ and $b=y'(0)$, you obtain
$$ y(t) = a+bt+(t-c)u(t-c). $$

Here, we use $u(t)$ to mean the unit heaviside function, which is 0 for $t<0$ and 1 for $t>0$. That should also give you your hint if you need to use Laplace transforms instead; Laplace transforms take heaviside functions into exponential shifts -- check the Wikipedia page on Laplace transforms for examples.

[edit] replaced typo of hessian with heaviside.

Comment: Yes, sorry. :-)