Construct the exact solution $u$ of this problem and describe the graph of $u$ and $u'$. Does the classical statement work?
Note that this book was intended for engineering undergraduates.
From Becker E., Carey G., and Oden J.'s Finite Elements, an Introduction Volume I, question 1.2.3:
Question:
Consider the boundary-value problem: $$ -u''(x) = \delta_{1/2}(x), \; \; \; \;  0 < x <1 \\ u(0) = 0 , \; \; \; \; u(1) =0$$
where $\delta_{1/2}$ is the Dirac delta corresponding to a point source at $x = (1/2)$. Construct the exact solution $u$ of this problem and describe the graphs of $u$ and $u'$ as functions of $x$. What does the plot of $u''$ look like? Does the classical statement of the problem given above make sense at $x = (1/2)$? Why?

Answer:
Function $u: [0, 1 ] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is "defined"" by $$u(x) = \begin{cases}-(x/4)  &&& 0 \le x < (1/2) \\\\ -(x^2/2) &&& x = (1/2) \\\\-(1/8) + (x/ 
4) &&& (1/2) < x \le 1 \end{cases}$$
If we naively and symbolically attempt to take the first and second derivatives, we have that  $$u'(x) = \begin{cases}-(1/4) &&& 0 \le x < (1/2) \\\\ -x &&& x = (1/2) \\\\-(1/4) &&& (1/2) < x \le 1 \end{cases} $$
and
$$u''(x) = \begin{cases}0&&& 0 \le x < (1/2) \\\\ -1 &&& x = (1/2) \\\\0 &&& (1/2) < x \le 1 \end{cases}$$
where the second derivative satisfies the problem statement. Graphically, the plot of $u$ resembles a triangular function, with a sharp change at $x = (1/2)$.
At this same point though, the first derivative is a jump function with a singular point at the jump; there is a negative constant-valued plateau to the left of $x = (1/2)$ point, and a positive, constant-valued plateau to the right. Then we have a singular point $f'(1/2) = -(1/2)$.
The "second derivative" is zero everywhere except for a singular point $f''(1/2) = -1$. However, the ability to even take this second derivative is absurd, given the discontinuity of the first derivative. As an extension of this absurdity, we can say that the classical statement of the problem is nonsense at $x = (1/2)$

Is this a fine enough way to do it, or would integrating and solving the BC problem over $[0, 1] \neg \{(1/2) \}$ be better? I was going to attempt that, but then you still have to address integrating or solving at $x = (1/2)$, which I didn't have a non-creaky way I can think of demonstrating for this. If you have a nicer way to solve and demonstrate this, I'd love to see it.

The delta function is not equal to 1 at its singularity point. It is not defined there at all

@whpowell96 W.R.T it's first and zeroth derivatives? Oden, et al. explicitly define it as being that value with it's second derivative at $x = (1/2)$. This question is given on page 4 of their book.

The integral of the delta function in any interval containing $1/2$ is 1, but it is still undefined there

@whpowell96 Of course, I understand what you are saying, but the question prompt is taken more or less out of the book. Have you read the page I cited?

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739177/how-can-you-solve-y-deltat-c?noredirect=1.

$u(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x}{2} & 0\le x<\frac{1}{2}
\
\text{undefined}  & x=\frac{1}{2}
\
-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}<x<1
\end{cases}$
